# one webView for multiple classes

Tags: java, android, webview

i have loads of links that open specific webpages. at the moment they are opening in browser.They are in many different classes, what i want to do is have one web View i can inflate or run that will respond to which ever activity i am running. ie so i can open downloads.class webpages, tutorials.class webpages. all from one web View. instead of a web view for every class. i think im explaining my self correctly but i am unsure of how to even start doing this my self. hoped you guys could help thanks

this is some of the code im using so far. but because its a fragment i cant do a public constructor. i want to be able to use the String url init to change the Url from another class

```
public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment {


private String curURL;

public void init(String url) {


    curURL = url;


}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,

                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View view = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.webviewlayout, container, false);
    init("http://www.mediafire.com/download/ezbkyava2qz44b5/AllCast.apk");
    if (curURL != null) {

        WebView webview = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.DownloadWebNav);

        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webview.setWebViewClient(new webClient());

        webview.loadUrl(curURL);

        webview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                        String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                        long contentLength) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }

    return view;

}

private class webClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        return false;

    }

}
```

}

Comment: is the webview in separated activity  or every activity has its webview?

Comment: so far ive have just made the webview xml. but i suppose i could make it its own activity. @hamza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this with a simple java enum technique.Lets say you have three web views that you wish to trigger from the same activity one at a time.

```
public enum MenuType {
     ABOUTUS, FAQS, TERMSANDCONDITION
}
```

Activity/fragment having three buttons that launches the webview

```
    // in OnCreate

    Button mClickButton1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clickButton1);
    mClickButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button mClickButton2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clickButton2);
    mClickButton2.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button mClickButton3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clickButton3);
    mClickButton3.setOnClickListener(this);

// somewhere else in your code

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case  R.id.clickButton1: {
            // launch ABOUT US webview.
            startWebViewActivity(MenuType.ABOUTUS);
                break;
            }

            case R.id.clickButton2: {
            // launch FAQS webview.
            startWebViewActivity(MenuType.FAQS);
                break;
            }

            case R.id.clickButton3: {
            // launch TERMSANDCONDITION webview.
            startWebViewActivity(MenuType.TERMSANDCONDITION);
                break;
            }

            default:
             break;
        }




// method triggered when button clicked
    private void startWebViewActivity(MenuType menuType) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(WebViewActivity.INTENT_MENUTYPE, menuType);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

`WebViewActivity.java` class

```
        public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompactActivity {

            public static final String INTENT_MENUTYPE = "intent_menu_type";

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /* webview layout with <Framelayout> as a child having id =container
       that gets replaced by a fragment at run time.
           [make your own layout here] 
    */
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
                Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
                if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey(INTENT_MENUTYPE)) {
                    MenuType menuType = (MenuType) bundle.getSerializable(INTENT_MENUTYPE);
                    openFragment(WebViewFragment.newInstance(menuType));
                }
            }


        public void openFragment(Fragment fragment) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.container,
                        fragment);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
            }
        }
```

`WebViewFragment.java`

```
public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private static final String TAG = WebViewFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    WebView mWebView;
    private MenuType mMenuType;
    private String mUrl;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mPullToLoad;


    public static WebViewFragment newInstance(MenuType menuType) {
       WebViewFragment fragment = new WebViewFragment();
        fragment.setMenuType(menuType);
        return fragment;
    }

    public void setMenuType(MenuType menuType) {
        this.mMenuType = menuType;
    }

    public WebViewFragment() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (mMenuType == MenuType.ABOUTUS) {
            mUrl = " valid about us url";
        } else if (mMenuType == MenuType.FAQS) {
            mUrl = " valid FAQS url";
        } else if (mMenuType == MenuType.TERMSANDCONDITION) {
            mUrl = "valid terms and conditions url";
        }

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_webview,
                container, false);
//      initialize views here.
        int progressColor1 = ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.primary_color);
        int progressColor2 = ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.primary_color_dark);
        int progressColor3 = ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.dark_blue);
        int progressColor4 = ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.light_orange);

        mPullToLoad.setColorSchemeColors(progressColor2,progressColor3,progressColor4,progressColor1);
        mPullToLoad.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                showRefreshDialog();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                dismissRefreshDialog();
            }
        });
        mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);
    }



    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {

            if(mWebView !=null) {
                mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);

        }

    }


    public void showRefreshDialog() {
        mPullToLoad.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(mPullToLoad != null)
                    mPullToLoad.setRefreshing(true);
            }
        });
    }


    public void dismissRefreshDialog() {
        if(mPullToLoad!=null && mPullToLoad.isShown() )
            mPullToLoad.setRefreshing(false);
    }
 }
```

`fragment_webview.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/pull_to_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

hope this helps!!

Comment: could i do this with an on item click instead of an on click @ishwor kafley?

Comment: you mean from inside an adapter? sure you can! not just only from an adapter,  but you can do this from anywhere!

Comment: i had a go last night @Ishwor Kafley. i got everything in and imported correctly after about six goes lol. but i couldnt figure out the base activity and masterFragment. i assumed the masterfragment was its own class. so i made one to match it. but didnt know what to put in side the class.

Comment: master fragment and base activities are just abstract classes defining the xml appearances ! I forgot to erase those :D ! you can have your own implementation if you have understood the logic!

Comment: removed those useless classes!